# Any way to introduce a separator into lightning:datatable row actions?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightning-datatable

In SLDS there is a `slds-has-divider_top-space` style that allows a separator to be displayed between groups of actions:

[image: SLDS menu]

and this class can be specified in e.g. a `lightning:menuItem`.

Is there any way to achieve a similar effect for the row actions of [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) that are setup via JavaScript i.e. to break up menus like this one:

[image: lightning:datatable menu]

Comment: There is no way to do it this way, I checked myself trying to achieve this by passing the class attribute to the action, but it was never added. The only way you could do it is probably just have a fixed CSS style bases on the list element and then add the border and padding.

Answer (score 3):

@Keith C
I didn't provide a solution but here is a fixed CSS example:

For the data table add a class:

```
lightning:datatable class="action-test"
```

Now in the Style section of the component add this CSS, in my case I want separator before 2nd element(CSS is copied from lightning design to match the same style):

```
.THIS .action-test .slds-dropdown :nth-child(2):before {    
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid #dddbda;
    margin-top: .5rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    display: block;}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

The downside is, having this fixed after specific element, you can also make CSS selector to find an option by name and then add separator.

Comment: That's further than I got. Thanks for posting, though yes being so hard coded it is problematic.